# errors when hosting the angular application through GitHub pages

Tags: angular, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

i came across the below error when i try to deploy my angular application to GitHub pages through

> angular-cli-ghpages

[image: error message]

these were bash commands that i used when pushing the website to the GitHub

`ng build --prod --base-href "https://dinith72.github.io/aiesecLoginForm/"`  - to create the build version

```
ngh --dir dist/AiesecLogin -m "adding request for python serve"
```

i tried the options mentioned in the above [git issue posted](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/12) but could not find a solution to my issue . 
Thank you very much in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use `travis-ci` for this is better and in every commit will automatically build and deploy github pages and it 's not that much complicated simply just add `travis.yml` and update baseurl in `angular.json` for build

like this:

`"baseHref": "https://username.github.io/repo-name/"`

as example in my case :

`"baseHref": "https://malbarmawi.github.io/angular-lessons/"`

travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "9"
dist: trusty
sudo: false

branches:
  only:
    - master

cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules

install:
  - npm i @angular/cli@6.2.4 -g
  - npm i

script:
  - ng build --prod
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  local_dir: dist/
  on:
    branch: master
```

finaly get [github token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) , you can check my [project](https://github.com/malbarmawi/angular-lessons)

this the article that help me with this [Deploying your Angular app to GitHub Pages using Travis-CI](https://medium.com/angularmedellin/deploying-your-angular-app-to-github-pages-using-travis-ci-baca2e1c30e7)

Comment: Thanks for the answer that helps a lot ...by the way the link to the article does not work but i was able to google and found it

Comment: i think u are referring to the above article https://medium.com/angularmedellin/deploying-your-angular-app-to-github-pages-using-travis-ci-baca2e1c30e7

Comment: @dinithjayabodhi yes it was broke  I just fixe d , thank you 